# Error: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `examcnpm`.`users_BEFORE_DELETE`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `examcnpm`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `examcnpm`.`users_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare id int;

    select id= (select userid from deleted);
    delete from Result where Result.userid=id;

    delete u from Users as u inner join deleted as r on u.userid=r.userid 
    where u.userid=id;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I would expect to see a reference to OLD. values in a delete trigger.

Comment: I don't understand??

Comment: Your first problem is select id= (select userid from deleted) which is causing an error. If you don't understand my reference to OLD. then you need to review the documentation for triggers specifically 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive' (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Thanks, but this is trigger SQL Server so how can transfer from syntax SQL to syntax mysql

Comment: In mysql you cannot action the table which caused the trigger to fire. What is the delete users attempting to do?

Comment: I want to delete user in table users. When I delete user, user have point in table result to delete too.

Comment: Not with you. when your execute a delete from users the trigger is fired and deletes from result (or it would if you had the syntax right) and after the before trigger completes the user is deleted. Why would you want to delete users in the trigger body?

Comment: I want to delete user and result of user delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear why you could want to delete from users in the trigger or why a before rather than an after query. But here's how to use OLD. to delete from result.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `users_BEFORE_DELETE`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `users_BEFORE_DELETE` after DELETE ON `u` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        delete from Result where Result.id=old.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For example

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> select id,username from u order by id limit 5;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  2 | Jane     |
|  3 | Ali      |
|  6 | Bruce    |
|  7 | Martha   |
|  8 | Sidney   |
+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from result order by id limit 10;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  8 |
+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> delete from u where id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,username from u order by id limit 5;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  3 | Ali      |
|  6 | Bruce    |
|  7 | Martha   |
|  8 | Sidney   |
| 10 | charlie  |
+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from result order by id limit 10;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  3 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  8 |
| 10 |
| 10 |
+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```